# Search for string in text file and print line until next tab \t

Tags: perl, parsing, grep, string-matching

I have a fairly complex text file `file1.txt` that hasn't been munged properly. The file is tab-delimited however, i.e. each string is separated by `\t`.

I would like to write a script/use a Unix command that parses this entire file for a certain string `string1:` which will print the line after the colon until stopping at `\t`.

The text file looks like this:

```
...kjdafhldkhlfak\tSTRING1:Iwanttokeepthis\tfadfasdafldafh\tSTRING1:andthis\tafsdkfasldh....
```

So the `grep` like function outputs

```
Iwanttokeepthis
andthis
```

In Perl, I know how to print a string if it occurs with

```
perl -wln -e 'print if /\bSTRING1\b/' file1.txt
```

How would one revise this to print the line between `STRING1:` and `\t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'STRING1:\K.*?(?=\t)' file
```

Output:

```
Iwanttokeepthis
andthis
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: `.*?` is a fragile construct. There's no problems in your particular pattern, but I like to avoid it whenever possible. You could also use `grep -Po 'STRING1:\K[^\t]*(?=\t)' file` or just `grep -Po 'STRING1:\K[^\t]*' file`

Answer (score 5):

With Perl:

```
$ echo $'kjdafhldkhlfak\tSTRING1:Iwanttokeepthis\tfadfasdafldafh\tSTRING1:andthis\tafsdkfasldh' > /tmp/file
perl -lne 'while (/STRING1:([^\t]+)\t/g) {print $1}' /tmp/file
Iwanttokeepthis
andthis
```

Or, as stated in comments:

```
$ perl -nle'print for /STRING1:([^\t]*)\t/g' /tmp/file
Iwanttokeepthis
andthis
```

Comment: Simpler: `perl -nle'print for /STRING1:([^\t]*)\t/g'`, or just `perl -nle'print for /STRING1:([^\t]*)/g'`